# Add date into table which is in relation with product in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have product and auction table. I want to add auction deadline on a specific table using form. when I submit the form the product_id in auction table is not populated and deadline shows time on which form is submited.

Here what I am trying:

I want that the create form get the deadline and store in auction table with product id so I can access it in show method of product.

**create.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
      <div class="mt-3" style="margin-left: 50px;">
       <h2>Add new product</h2>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 
    'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'w-50 py-3']) !!}
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('name', 'Product Name')}}
        {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product Name'])}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('description', 'Product Description')}}
        {{Form::textarea('description', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product Description', 'rows' => '4'])}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::Label('category', 'Category') !!}
        <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
          @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('price', 'Product Price')}}
        {{Form::number('price', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product Price'])}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('deadline', 'Auction Deadline')}}
        {{Form::date('{{$auction->deadline}}', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('image', 'Product Image')}}
        {{Form::file('image', ['class' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Product Image'])}}
      </div>
      {{Form::submit('Upload Product', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
 </div>   
 @endsection
```

**Product Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'description', 'image',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function auction()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Auction');
    }
}
```

**ProductsController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use App\Auction;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();

        $products = Product::with('category')->latest()->paginate(3);

        return view('products.index' ,compact('categories', 'products'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::all(['id', 'name']);
        return view('products.create', compact('categories',$categories));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|nullable',
        ]);

        // Create Product
        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = request('name');
        $product->description = request('description');
        $product->category_id = request('category_id');
        $product->price = request('price');
        $product->image = $fileNameToStore;
        $product->save();

        $auction = new Auction();
        $auction->deadline = request('deadline');
        $auction->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success', 'Product Created');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);

        return view('products.show', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

Comment: please update your question with your controller which including store method

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just creating auction, where is the relation? Delete `$product->save();` line. After the   `$auction->save();` add this line:

```
$product->auction()->associate($auction);
$product->save();
```

Final Store method

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|nullable',
    ]);

    // Create Product
    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = request('name');
    $product->description = request('description');
    $product->category_id = request('category_id');
    $product->price = request('price');
    $product->image = $fileNameToStore;

    $auction = new Auction();
    $auction->deadline = request('deadline');
    $auction->save();

    $product->auction()->associate($auction);
    $product->save();

    return redirect('/products')->with('success', 'Product Created');
}
```

**Update for Irrelevant Blade problem**

This line is wrong:

```
{{Form::date('{{$auction->deadline}}', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

You are using blade close string tag in blade string tag.
Should be:

```
{{Form::date('deadline', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

If auction variable has been passing from controller this will work

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\resources\views\products\create.blade.php)

Comment: This is your syntax error. Please look your blade. This is not relevant this question. By anyway, i will edit my answer

Comment: I don't know it will work or not before I check it. Should I start another question for it?

Comment: Undefined variable: auction (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\auction\resources\views\products\create.blade.php)

Comment: I didn't get it sorry. I am beginner

Comment: Please don't use undefined variable as label. I updated date field in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it works, still has some issue but I will try to fix it